# SVG background image not working on iPhone 4?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG that doesnt render on an iPhone 4 but appears to work fine on all other browsers. Im wondering if it could be the transform property not being supported?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="38" height="38" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <use x="0.084832" y="-0.670279" transform="matrix(0.995734, 0, 0, 0.995734, -0.0756826, 1.1509)" xlink:href="#svg_2" id="svg_3"/>
  <g id="svg_4"/>
 </g>
 <defs>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 40 40" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg_2">
   <g id="svg_1">
    <path d="m19.700001,11.2c-0.400002,-1.3 -0.6,-5 -1.6,-7.2c0,-0.1 0,-0.1 0,-0.2c-0.200001,-0.4 -0.4,-0.8 -0.800001,-1.1c0,0 0,0 0,0c-0.099998,-0.1 -0.199999,-0.1 -0.299999,-0.2c0,0 -0.1,0 -0.1,-0.1c0,0 0,0 -0.1,0c-0.299999,-0.1 -0.5,-0.2 -0.799999,-0.3c-1.6,-0.3 -3.1,0.7 -4.9,2c-1.700001,1.2 -3.8,1.8 -5.400001,2.1c-2.5,0.3 -3.7,0.6 -4.4,1c0,0 0,0 0,0c-0.2,0.1 -0.3,0.2 -0.4,0.3c0,0 0,0 -0.1,0c-0.1,0.1 -0.1,0.2 -0.2,0.3c-0.2,0.2 -0.3,0.4 -0.4,0.599999c0,0 0,0 0,0.1c-0.1,0.2 -0.2,0.5 -0.2,0.8c0,0.3 0,0.7 0.2,1c0,0 0,0.099999 0.1,0.099999c0.6,1.900001 2.5,4.3 3.4,6.200001c1.3,2.699999 2.1,4.5 3.1,5.4c0.9,0.799999 3.2,2.299999 6.4,4.4c3.599999,1.6 5.2,-0.9 5.500001,-2.199999c0.299999,-1.200001 1.299999,-4.700001 1.699999,-6.300001c0.4,-1.6 -0.199999,-5 -0.699999,-6.7l0,0zm-5.400001,-0.599999c0.5,-0.3 1.4,-0.5 2.3,-0.3c-0.200001,0.7 -0.6,1.4 -1.400001,1.9c-0.8,0.5 -1.3,0.400001 -2,0.1c0,-0.6 0.2,-1.2 1.1,-1.7l0,0zm-6.5,4.299999c-1,0.200001 -1.7,-0.099999 -2.3,-0.5c0.6,-0.7 1.4,-1.2 2,-1.299999c1,-0.200001 1.5,0.099999 1.9,0.599999c-0.4,0.6 -0.7,1 -1.599999,1.2l0,0zm6.8,7.1c-2.1,0.799999 -4.5,-0.200001 -5.200001,-2.299999c-0.099999,-0.200001 -0.099999,-0.400002 -0.2,-0.700001c1,1.6 3,2.299999 4.900001,1.6c1.9,-0.700001 3,-2.6 2.699999,-4.4c0.1,0.199999 0.200001,0.4 0.300001,0.599998c0.799999,2.1 -0.4,4.400002 -2.5,5.200001l0,0z" fill="#B39C0B" id="svg_5"/>
    <path d="m40,21.6c0,-0.1 0,-0.200001 0,-0.300001c0,0 0,-0.099998 0,-0.099998c0,0 0,0 0,-0.1c-0.099998,-0.300001 -0.200001,-0.6 -0.400002,-0.800001c-0.799999,-1.299999 -2.599998,-1.799999 -4.799999,-2.199999c-2.099998,-0.4 -3.9,-1.6 -5.299999,-2.5c-1.9,-1.6 -2.9,-2.3 -3.700001,-2.5c0,0 0,0 0,0c-0.199999,0 -0.299999,-0.1 -0.5,-0.1c0,0 0,0 -0.099998,0c-0.1,0 -0.200001,0 -0.300001,0c-0.299999,0 -0.5,0.1 -0.699999,0.2c0,0 0,0 -0.1,0c-0.300001,0.1 -0.5,0.2 -0.700001,0.400001c-0.299999,0.2 -0.5,0.5 -0.6,0.799999c0,0 0,0.1 -0.099998,0.1c-1,1.799999 -1.400002,4.799999 -2.1,6.700001c-1,2.799999 -1.700001,4.599998 -1.700001,5.9c0,1.199999 0.5,3.9 1.200001,7.699999c1.299999,3.700012 4.199999,3.100002 5.4,2.5c1.1,-0.599991 4.299999,-2.299988 5.700001,-3.099991c1.5,-0.799999 3.5,-3.600008 4.399998,-5.100008c0.700001,-1.200001 3.200001,-3.9 4.200001,-6.099991c0,-0.1 0.100002,-0.1 0.100002,-0.20001c0,-0.29999 0.099998,-0.699999 0.099998,-1.199999c0,0 0,0 0,0l0,0zm-14.799999,-0.200001c0.9,0.4 1.299999,1.1 1.5,1.800001c-1,0.199999 -1.900002,0.099998 -2.300001,-0.200001c-0.9,-0.4 -1.1,-1 -1.1,-1.6c0.5,-0.299999 1,-0.4 1.900002,0l0,0zm3.599998,11.800001c-0.099998,0.200001 -0.199999,0.399998 -0.4,0.599998c0.6,-1.799999 -0.299999,-3.799999 -2.1,-4.799999c-1.799999,-0.9 -4,-0.4 -5.099998,1.1c0.099998,-0.200001 0.099998,-0.4 0.199999,-0.700001c1,-1.9 3.4,-2.699999 5.5,-1.699999c2,1.099998 2.9,3.5 1.9,5.5zm3.200001,-6.400002c-0.5,-0.199999 -1.200001,-0.799999 -1.700001,-1.599998c0.700001,-0.300001 1.400002,-0.400002 2.299999,-0.1s1.200001,0.799999 1.300003,1.5c-0.5,0.4 -1,0.6 -1.900002,0.199999l0,0z" fill="#B39C0B" id="svg_6"/>
   </g>
  </symbol>
 </defs>
</svg>
```

Ive tried using all of these optimizers:

https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/

http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-editor

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-svgmin

Im using spritesmith. When I view the generated sprite on an iPhone 4 most of the icons are there but my problem SVG is not visible.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-spritesmith

Here is my full sprite, funnily enough the dropbox viewer also doesn't render all of the icons. If you save the svg and open it in Chrome you will see all of them: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o981ljy0cs9ued/sprite-d5c1601f.svg?dl=0

UPDATE - Saving the file with Illustrator fixes this issue however it would still be nice to have an automated solution or linting to provide a warning for future files.

Comment: You can't change the question once it has an answer in a way that invalidates that answer, it's not fair on the answerer. If you have another question ask it separately.  You can always refer to this question in your new question if you feel it will provide additional context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `<defs>` section before the `<use>`. IIRC older Safari/Webkit had a bug with forward references.

Ie. rearrange the file so the  order of tags looks like this:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <symbol>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Apologies, I've changed the focus of my question a bit.